# How to fix path.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a db layer that runs in port 3xxx and a webUI that runs on port 4xxx. The webUI communicates with the db layer
and works without a problem when i access from port 4xxx (localhost:4xxx). But when i type localhost:3xxx(the server port) i have the following error:

!!!Note i have not developed this code

TypeError: path.json is not a function

```
at app.get ../server.js:22:23)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (../layer.js:95:5)
at next (../route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (../route.js:112:3)
```

O have the following code:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const port = 3125;
const app = express_1.default();
app.use(express_1.default.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});
app.use('/', api);
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(path.json(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("server is running on localhost: " + port);
});
```

Is there any solution/way that if I access the server directly i wont get an error?

Comment: `path.json` is nothing.. and you might want `path.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `path.join(...)` instead of `path.json(...)`